# can not connect to phoenix using python phoenixdb library

Tags: python, apache-phoenix

I have Phoenix which is integrated with HBase.
I am trying to access phoenix from python code using pythondb library, and I have started the QueryServer using

```
bin/queryserver.py start
```

But after the connect statement I get the following error:

```
database_url = 'http://localhost:8765/'
conn = phoenixdb.connect(database_url, autocommit=True)
```

InternalError: ('Cannot find parser for', None, None, None)

and this is the error from log:

> 2016-08-10 14:24:07,987 WARN org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel: /
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find parser for    at
>   org.apache.calcite.avatica.remote.ProtobufTranslationImpl.getParserForRequest(ProtobufTranslationImpl.java:182)
>     at
>   org.apache.calcite.avatica.remote.ProtobufTranslationImpl.parseRequest(ProtobufTranslationImpl.java:239)
>     at
>   org.apache.calcite.avatica.remote.ProtobufHandler.decode(ProtobufHandler.java:42)
>     at
>   org.apache.calcite.avatica.remote.ProtobufHandler.decode(ProtobufHandler.java:28)
>     at
>   org.apache.calcite.avatica.remote.AbstractHandler.apply(AbstractHandler.java:95)
>     at
>   org.apache.calcite.avatica.remote.ProtobufHandler.apply(ProtobufHandler.java:38)
>     at
>   org.apache.calcite.avatica.server.AvaticaProtobufHandler.handle(AvaticaProtobufHandler.java:68)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList.handle(HandlerList.java:52)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:497)  at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:245)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: Although I can successfully connect to sql shell using:   bin/sqlline-thin.py http://localhost:8765

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was because I was using Phoenix 4.7 even I have started the server using

```
./bin/queryserver.py start -Dphoenix.queryserver.serialization=JSON
```

After remove Phoenix 4.7 and install 4.6 the connection from python can be established successfully.

I hope someone will use this tip :)
Thanks!